# How to Keep showing the dialog when the Activity is change

Tags: android, dialog

I used a custom dialog as a notify in the app, so I want it to keep show even the activity is changing, can it? or I should use other thing?

Comment: I finally use Toast ==

Answer (score -1):

Use `getApplicationContext()`.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Did you try it? The problem I usually get is exception `Windows:BadToken ...` when trying to use the application context to show a dialog.

Comment: I have a class like this: public class MyDialog extends Dialog public MyDialog (final Context context, String title, final String content, String item) so I change Dialog to AlertDialog ?

Comment: I am sure this must throw Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running? Did you check before posting the answer?